# How to get 100 score in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, scoring

I just installed ElasticSearch service and index some article titles with it.  When I search the exact title of an article which is in the index I expect to get 100 as score for it in the search result. But I am given 63 not 100.

Why is it so? I use match query. Should I change it?

Comment: Why would you expect it to be `100`? It's not a percentage. Read more on [how default scoring function works in Elasticsearch](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/practical-scoring-function.html), and on [how to modify score calculation yourself](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-function-score-query.html).

Answer (score 0):

Do not consider score to be a match percentage, rather you may want to check as to why the score was 63 and try to boost it if you want so, score would be considered only to rank certain documents over another.

You can check the formula for score calculation using below endpoint.

EXPLAIN API

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-explain.html